# numpy dot product returns nan between two arrays of no nan element or inf

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, product

I'm using Numpy *dot* function to calculate the dot product between two arrays. The problem is that it returns a lot of *nan* in the result array, while there is no *nan* in any of the two arrays. I also checked for the existence of *inf* in both, but nothing like that either. The data type of both arrays is **float64** and the minimum and maximum of the two arrays are as follow:

```
min=0   max=255       min=-.999  max=.979
```

What is going wrong I don't know. Is this an overflow issue or something else. Hope someone can give me a hint.

Comment: Pick any nan position say (x,y) from the output and manually inspect `input1[x]` and `input2[:,y]` for NaNs /Infs?

Comment: Can you give a MWE?

Comment: I would suspect overflow, but the numbers involved aren't large enough for that to happen. Can you show us example data (or short code that would generate example data) that demonstrates the NaN problem?

Comment: How did you check for NaNs and Infs in the inputs?

Comment: Are you sure you are expecting an array to be returned. If you are taking the scalar (dot) product between two arrays then you should expect a scalar to be returned, not an array?

Comment: For each of the arrays, I use numpy.isnan(array).sum() and numpy.isinf(array).sum() and for both array I get zero. I also did the same thing for columns with nan as their product result. But, I cannot see any nan or inf in any of them.

Comment: @ oliversm according to numpy,  numpy.dot: For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b:

Comment: What's the shape of these arrays?

Comment: The shapes are: (10L,170L) and (170L,)